# Saving output from powerset

Tags: python, python-3.x, powerset

I recently started to learn something about the powerset-possibility with python. The code which i use looks as followed:

```
 def printPowerSet(set,set_size): 

    # set_size of power set of a set 
    # with set_size n is (2**n -1) 
    pow_set_size = (int) (math.pow(2, set_size)) 
    counter = 0 
    j = 0 
    zahl = 0  #um zu sehen, wie viele Kombinationsmöglichkeiten existieren
    # Run from counter 000..0 to 111..1 
    for counter in range(0, pow_set_size): 
        for j in range(0, set_size): 

            # Check if jth bit in the  
            # counter is set If set then  
            # print jth element from set  
            if((counter & (1 << j)) > 0): 
                print(set[j], end="")
        print("")
        zahl = zahl+1
    print(zahl)
# Driver program to test printPowerSet 
set = variants           
printPowerSet(set, len(set))
```

the variable variable has the following data:

```
>>> variants
['(4|W)', '(12|T)', '(21|V)', '(31|S)', '(41|Q)', '(42|E)', '(62|W)',
'(78|A)', '(84|C)', '(84|H)', '(89|C)', '(89|H)', '(93|V)', '(114|G)', '(119|R)']
```

The output of the function gives me the following output(here a glipmse):

```
(31|S)(41|Q)(62|W)(78|A)(84|C)(84|H)(89|C)(89|H)(93|V)(114|G)(119|R)
(4|W)(31|S)(41|Q)(62|W)(78|A)(84|C)(84|H)(89|C)(89|H)(93|V)(114|G)(119|R)
(12|T)(31|S)(41|Q)(62|W)(78|A)(84|C)(84|H)(89|C)(89|H)(93|V)(114|G)(119|R)
(4|W)(12|T)(31|S)(41|Q)(62|W)(78|A)(84|C)(84|H)(89|C)(89|H)(93|V)(114|G)(119|R)
(21|V)(31|S)(41|Q)(62|W)(78|A)(84|C)(84|H)(89|C)(89|H)(93|V)(114|G)(119|R)
(4|W)(21|V)(31|S)(41|Q)(62|W)(78|A)(84|C)(84|H)(89|C)(89|H)(93|V)(114|G)(119|R)
(12|T)(21|V)(31|S)(41|Q)(62|W)(78|A)(84|C)(84|H)(89|C)(89|H)(93|V)(114|G)(119|R)
(4|W)(12|T)(21|V)(31|S)(41|Q)(62|W)(78|A)(84|C)(84|H)(89|C)(89|H)(93|V)(114|G)(119|R)
(42|E)(62|W)(78|A)(84|C)(84|H)(89|C)(89|H)(93|V)(114|G)(119|R)
(4|W)(42|E)(62|W)(78|A)(84|C)(84|H)(89|C)(89|H)(93|V)(114|G)(119|R)
(12|T)(42|E)(62|W)(78|A)(84|C)(84|H)(89|C)(89|H)(93|V)(114|G)(119|R)
(4|W)(12|T)(42|E)(62|W)(78|A)(84|C)(84|H)(89|C)(89|H)(93|V)(114|G)(119|R)
(21|V)(42|E)(62|W)(78|A)(84|C)(84|H)(89|C)(89|H)(93|V)(114|G)(119|R)
(4|W)(21|V)(42|E)(62|W)(78|A)(84|C)(84|H)(89|C)(89|H)(93|V)(114|G)(119|R)
(12|T)(21|V)(42|E)(62|W)(78|A)(84|C)(84|H)(89|C)(89|H)(93|V)(114|G)(119|R)
(4|W)(12|T)(21|V)(42|E)(62|W)(78|A)(84|C)(84|H)(89|C)(89|H)(93|V)(114|G)(119|R)
(31|S)(42|E)(62|W)(78|A)(84|C)(84|H)(89|C)(89|H)(93|V)(114|G)(119|R)
(4|W)(31|S)(42|E)(62|W)(78|A)(84|C)(84|H)(89|C)(89|H)(93|V)(114|G)(119|R)
(12|T)(31|S)(42|E)(62|W)(78|A)(84|C)(84|H)(89|C)(89|H)(93|V)(114|G)(119|R)
(4|W)(12|T)(31|S)(42|E)(62|W)(78|A)(84|C)(84|H)(89|C)(89|H)(93|V)(114|G)(119|R)
(21|V)(31|S)(42|E)(62|W)(78|A)(84|C)(84|H)(89|C)(89|H)(93|V)(114|G)(119|R)
```

Good thing is that the powerset function does give me all combinations. Every combination-possibility is given in a single line.  This step is done in the if-loop. Can someone give me an idea or a way, how i can save the output in a variable, and not printing it out? I want to use this step/output for my further analysis. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Trun print statements into string concatenations.

```
def printPowerSet(set,set_size): 
    # Set_size of power set of a set 
    # with set_size n is (2**n -1) 
    pow_set_size = (int) (math.pow(2, set_size)) 
    counter = 0 
    j = 0 
    zahl = 0  # Um zu sehen, wie viele Kombinationsmöglichkeiten existieren
    result = ""  # String to store the result

    # Run from counter 000..0 to 111..1 
    for counter in range(0, pow_set_size): 
        for j in range(0, set_size): 

            # Check if jth bit in the  
            # counter is set If set then  
            # print jth element from set  
            if((counter & (1 << j)) > 0):
                result += str(set[j])

        result += "\n"
        zahl += 1

    return result + "\n" + str(zahl)

# Driver program to test printPowerSet 
set = variants           
result = printPowerSet(set, len(set)) 

print("Result:")
print(result)
```

Comment: why did i not think of that way?  Thank you very much!

Comment: Don't mention it, if you found it useful give an upvote.